# Android use of absolute layout

Tags: android

can we use absolute layout for designing. I need to prepare a mock-up demo app for an big application and i don't have much of time. So i have decided to do it vy setting the screenshot of the page as background and placing the mandatory controls over it using absolute layout. Will it work on the tablets as i am testing with emulators only. hoping for better responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason you physically can't use `AbsoluteLayout` if that's what you're asking.  It's deprecated, but it's still part of the API.  It's just very unwise to use it for production of software that's going to be on multiple devices.  If it's just a mock-up for a device or size then go ahead, but keep in mind that the final design will have layouts shifting around slightly if you plan on using it on different sized devices.

Answer (score 1):

AbsoluteLayout is not recommended , as it gets tied to a particular screen size. 
Use Relative Layout instead which can scale and adjust UI components depending on the screen width and height available.

Comment: right now i am working for tablet with 10.1 Inches (WXGA) only. Will it work on tablets

Answer (score 0):

The AbsoluteLayout has been [deprecated](http://file:///F:/Android/docs/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html).

Actually, other layouts like RelativeLayout and LinearLayout could meet your demands theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by many AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and is not at all recommended.